# Horizontally align links so that they are evenly spaced within the nav

Tags: html, css, nav

UPDATE: Sorry for the confusion, I *thought* I couldn't use a table, but apparently I can.

I'm trying to find out how to evenly space links within the nav so that they have an equal amount of space between them. I have researched a little and all the suggestions suggest using a list or table, which I cannot use (I think).

```css
.title {
  float: left;
  font: bold 52px Moon, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.top {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Moon;
  src: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/fonts/Moon%20Bold.otf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Coco;
  src: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/fonts/CocoPuff-Regular.ttf);
}
nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.35em;
  font-family: Coco, Arial;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.cl-effect-4 a {
  padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.cl-effect-4 a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.cl-effect-4 a:hover::after,
.cl-effect-4 a:focus::after {
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
nav {
  float: left
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="title">
    Codecatek
  </div>
  <nav class="cl-effect-4">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: [Equidistant Objects with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way *is* to use a table with width 100% and td's text-align center. Could you please explain why you can't use it?

Or, you *could* use the following code:

```css
body{background:black;}
nav{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

nav > a{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <nav>
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <a href="">TEST</a>
    <a href="">TEST</a>
  </nav>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** You might want to change the width of the nav to suit your webpage.

Comment: When I add that to my code, all it does is remove padding and margin :/

Comment: What does it remove the padding and margin for?

Comment: I don't know, i'm just having problems getting it to work. Can you provide a snippit with your answer applied to the code I provided? It would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this, and use the `justify-content: space-around` css property.

Great intro to flexbox here:
http://flexboxin5.com/

Comment: Could you explain how to apply it to code snippet? It would be a big help

Comment: May or may not be an issue for OP, support for [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c5kcybyd/

I have added margin to anchor links under nav

```
nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.35em;
  font-family: Coco, Arial;
   margin-left:30px;

}
```